# My IIS redirect rule is not working via web.config

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

I have a redirect rule that I am trying to create using web.config. I am trying to redirect

from the below page:

https://example.org/content/content.php?PrintMe=0&PgName=gothedistance

to this page:

https://example.org/gothedistance

My url redirect rule looks like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="content.php$" />
                <conditions>  
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="PrintMe=0&PgName=gothedistance" />  
            </conditions> 
            <action type="Redirect" url="gothedistance" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Read the trace log and see why https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @LexLi It's an internal server error 500 but I don't know why. I can't use the trace suggestiong because url rewrite does not show up for my trace options

Comment: What kind of 500? 500.19? Maybe you didn't even install IIS URL Rewrite module.